# Wordpress Won't Send Email When a User Register

Tags: email, user-registration

When a user registers on my wordpress site, it does not send them an email containing the password.

I do notice that an email was sent when a users email is `@mydomain.com`, but for others let say gmail.com or yahoo.com, it does not send an email.

How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what your using as your backend (eg: cpanel). But can you send an email from your server to gmail.com or yahoo.com email address? Also are you saying that when the user uses your domain name, then the email is sent?

Comment: im using cpanel. I can send in webmail to gmail.com email address. Yes, the email was sent when a user from my domain name.

Comment: the problem is on wordpress. :-(

Comment: Does the reset password send emails? Is there anything in your log file?

Comment: reset password only work for email with mydomain, for other's like gmail.com or yahoo.com, it wont.

Comment: i tried a lot of SMTP plugin, but only http://hel.io/wordpress/smtp/ work without problem with my existing plugins.

Answer (score 2):

While not a *solution* as such, I would suggest you send a couple of test emails to isolate the issue and verify how and where things go wrong. Perhaps your email is actually sent, but rejected by the remote mail server due to missing some headers etc. The code below might help you determine this. Temporarily put it in `functions.php`. [`wp_mail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) will return `true` on success and `false` otherwise.

```
function email_test() {
    $test1 = wp_mail( user@yourdomain.com, "Test 1", "Just testing" );
    $test2 = wp_mail( user@otherdomain.com, "Test 2", "Just testing some more" );

    var_dump($test1);
    var_dump($test2);
    var_dump(ini_get('smtp_port'));

    die();
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'email_test');
```

There are a [few SMTP related PHP settings](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) which might influence the behavior of `mail()` and in turn `wp_mail()`. If you are using shared hosting I would suggest you simply describe the problem to you hosting provider and have them adjust the settings, or hopefully they'll be able at least to point you in the right direction.

I have also seen some issues with email being sent, but rejected by the remote server due to missing headers. While `wp_mail` should take care of most of these, adding headers like `From`, `Reply-To`, `Return-Path`, `Organization`, `X-PHP-Script` might sometimes help (check out the fourth argument for `wp_mail`).